# wpa_supplicant.conf file become empty

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, headless, wpa

I did headless setup of the Pi 3B+ and what I've done was:

1. Flashed the last OS on the SD card (Raspbian Stretch full 2018-11-13)
2. Created two files in the root directory of the SD card:

   - `wpa_supplicant.conf` with the contents I will show below
   - `ssh` (empty)

After that my Pi successfully connected to my WiFi network and I was able to SSH into it.

However when I tried to look into `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` which supposed to contain network information - it was empty.

I looked into the file with

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I remember that last time I did that thing with RPi 3B (not plus) this file contained my networks.

Does anybody have an ideo why I see this file empty?

My wpa_supplicant.conf file is the following:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=RU

network={
    ssid="myWiFiname"
    psk="myWifipass"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

All spaces I replaced for TABs. Bythe way: is it really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the `.wpa_supplicant.conf.swp` hidden file stored in the same directory.

As I removed this file, everything worked as expected.